# Django authentication LDAP unable to find user

Tags: python, django, ldap

I'm working on a django project and I'm trying to authenticate my APP against LDAP server.
settings.py:

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://domain.local"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "domain\django"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "<Password>"

AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=local",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
```

Code:

```
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend
auth = LDAPBackend()
auth.authenticate(username="omers", password="<password>")
```

For now I'm just using the shell

When I do tcpdump I see the LDAP packet but for some reason the LDAP server can't find my user but I know it's exist, what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: be careful about that string: `"domain\django"`. Should be `r"domain\django"` (in that case it works, though). And can you post the error message?

Comment: Hi, I don't know where the error message is, just did a tcpdump..

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
I found the answer, my AD doesn't use UID but CN so instead of

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=local",
ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")
```

I used

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=local",
ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(cn=%(user)s)")
```